# How do I obtain a Chart instance for Chart.js

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I am using Python/Django with the default Django templates.
I have this in the head (other django static files in this location work fine):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static "js/Chart.min.js" %}"></script>
```

Naturally, I have Chart.min.js extracted from the master Chart.js download into the static js directory.

In my body I have:

```
<div class="graph">
    <canvas id="dgraph" width="600" height="400"></canvas>              
</div>
```

Also in the body I have:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static "js/stuff.js" %}"></script>
```

In stuff.js I have:

```
    var data = [
    {
        value: 20,
        color:"#878BB6"
    },
    {
        value : 40,
        color : "#4ACAB4"
    },
    {
        value : 10,
        color : "#FF8153"
    },
    {
        value : 30,
        color : "#FFEA88"
    }
];
```

// Get the context of the canvas element we want to select

```
var ctx = document.getElementById("dgraph").getContext("2d");
new Chart(ctx).Doughnut(data, {});
```

However, when I try and display this in a browser (Chrome as it happens) I see this in the console:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Chart is not defined
```

Where on earth is the Chart object obtained from? It seems to be pretty fundamental and I feel as if I've followed every instruction available on google and stackoverflow.  Please help!

Answer (score 3):

The `Chart` object is defined in [Chart.min.js](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nnnick/Chart.js/master/Chart.min.js). It looks like that script isn't being loaded.

I think you're missing quotes around the value of the `src` attribute in the `<script>` tag in your header - try:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/Chart.min.js' %}"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks, tried that with a single quote and double quotes and no joy unfortunately.  Good point though @rphv, I hadn't noticed that on my Chart.min.js src link, I'm now using a single quote on the inner text and doubles on the whole of the src link.

Answer (score 1):

I discovered that by moving the Chart.min.js included line BELOW the jQuery included line, it springs into life.  Like so:

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/Chart.min.js' %}"></script>
```

Presumably Chart.js is dependent on jQuery.

Comment: No, Chart.js does not depend on jQuery - [here's an example](http://jsfiddle.net/rphv/brLkbnLh/). However there may be something else going on in your case, e.g. a global namespace collision.

Comment: I don't know why my code works now when it didn't before then.  I have no reference to the variable Chart anywhere apart from when using Chart.js.